# How to Download file in chunks

Tags: vb.net

My program downloads a file from an FTP server once a week when a new file i added. The server is slow because of all the traffic around the time of the upload, which slows down the download to the point in which my program will crash. The file is about 2.5-3 GB and with a few people downloading at once it can take up to 2-3 hours for it to download. My problem is that when my program crashes i have to start all over again. Is there someway i can modify my current code to split up the download in multible parts and then combine them later. Ultimately what i would like to have is a 3 threaded download with 1 starting at 0 gb, 1 gb and 2 gb and have all 3 downloading at the same time and then combining them when they are all done. Hope you can guide me in the right dirrection!

```
Public Event DownloadProgressChanged As DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Download AddHandler
    wc = New WebClient()
    AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, Sub(s As Object, ByVal e1 As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
                                               Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() StatusToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Status: Downloading (" & Math.Round(e1.BytesReceived / e1.TotalBytesToReceive * 100, 2).ToString("0.00") & " %)"))

                                               lastUpdate = Now
                                               If e1.ProgressPercentage = 100 Then downloaded = True
                                               End Sub 
End sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("ftp://user:password@ip/ESStatistikListeModtag/" & XML), downloadPath & XML)
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38558598/1070452

Comment: You could make use of the [FtpWebRequest.ContentOffset Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) to resume the download at the current length of the downloaded file. Note that using more than one thread is unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: This may end up being closed as a duplicate, but you really shouldn't write code like that `AddHandler` line. It's a challenge to read, and worse to debug.

Comment: The `ContentOffset` property of an `FtpWebRequest` can also be used to implement multi-part downloads. For instance, if want to download in three threads simultaneously then you get the `ContentLength` and then set the `ContentOffset` to zero, one third of the length and two thirds of the length for three `FtpWebRequest` objects. You'd probably still want to consider allowing for resuming though.